# How to get rid of space and align two objects in one line in css/html?

Tags: css, button

I have tried using firebug to locate the problem, but cannot find the solution to the following at this url :

1. How to get rid of the space between the image and the text?  For example, the gap between the image of lego-like bags and the text "AboveHere    Concept"
2. How to align these two social buttons in one line?  I have set the twitternews class width to 90px and the facebooknews iframe to a width of 90px, but this does not work.  I also have these two buttons in a block with a width set to 200px, but this does not seem to work either.

Comment: It seem to be just a `<p>`with no class or id added to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your

```
<p>
```

tags in the post-body divs have a top and bottom margin of 1em. that's why there's a lot of space in there. take those out

```
.post-body p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

you need to set .facebooknews div to have a smaller width, not the iframe

```
div.grid-item .facebooknews {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I looked for all the <p> and added the margin:0;, but there is still a gap.  I added the width and height for the .facebooknews and that did the job.  Thx

Comment: your p style is not specific enough if it doesn't reset to 0. try the above but add !important. also delete the <br> above the description p here's a screenie of what i did: http://tinypic.com/r/2usbbxf/7

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the style `margin-top: 0px` to the `P` tag that the "AboveHere Concept" text is in. Also remove the `<br>` thats right before the text. It will move everything up.

2) facebooknews add a `width: 100px;` and it will fit.